# How to securely send message (jwt token) from Website to extension's content script/background?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to securely send a message (jwt token) from my website to my extension's content script/background, but it seems like `chrome.runtime` is unavailable (i.e. `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` throws error) in the website's context.(not extension's context).

`website`

```
    // Send a message to the extension
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      extensionId,
      { action: 'auth-token', data: token },
      (response) => {
        if (response.success) {
          // Authentication succeeded
          console.log('done');
        } else {
          // Authentication failed
          console.log('failed');
        }
      }
    );
```

`extension background`

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
      console.log('========> ', { message, sender });
    }
  );
```

`extension manifest v3`

```
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://my-website.com/*"]
  },
```

how to achieve this, any idea?

Comment: The code is correct. Just make sure to reload the extension in chrome://extensions page, then reload the tab. [How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029)

Comment: I'm aware of that a long time ago. My question is My website build stops because `chrome.runtime` isn't available in javascript in my website.

Comment: Please reopen my question. You wrongly assumed my question is duplicate.

Comment: Since the code is correct, the only other explanation is a bug in Chrome, which you can report in https://crbug.com.

Comment: BTW a common mistake is to omit `www.` in `matches` because [Chrome hides it from the address bar](https://superuser.com/a/1498561).